# Teradata datatypes to hive datatypes incompatibility

Tags: hive, teradata

how to map Teradata data types to hive datatypes, for ex: in TD DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' COMPRESS (DATE '2013-10-09',DATE '2014-02-25'),. in hive we can use it as DATE.  but whenever we load data to hive table it show as NULL... please help me in this regard... Thank you

Comment: If you have a field in Hive defined as something other than a string, and it displays NULL when you have data in the files, the data does not match what hive expects.  For example, if you define a field as integer, but the file has 'ABC', hive will show null.

Comment: is the hive table - parquet ?..

Comment: How are you loading the data to hive?

Comment: we are loading data on hive LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'PATH' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE table name